# ¿Existe alguna manera de poder almacenar en memoria el contenido de un InputStream? (Android)

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Android, en la cual todo usuario que desee utilizar la aplicación, deberá de ingresar su cuenta de correo electrónico institucional; para mi caso en particular, todas las cuentas son de Microsoft Office 365.

Tomando como referencia el tipo de cuentas que utilizaran los usuarios, decidí utilizar la **API** **Microsoft Graph** para Android y de esta manera validar las credenciales que serán ingresadas en la aplicación; además de obtener datos de interés de la cuenta institucional ingresada, tales como: nombre de usuario, puesto, fotografía de perfil (en caso de que el usuario disponga de una), etc.

Después de implementar la API, y de realizar muchas pruebas, he logrado obtener los datos que necesito de manera correcta, sin embargo, tengo el siguiente problema:

La fotografía de perfil, la obtengo a través de un **InputStream**, y por medio de una tarea en segundo plano, es establecida dentro de un **ImageView**.

El problema en sí, es que al cambiar la orientación del dispositivo móvil en donde se esta ejecutando la aplicación, se vuelve a ejecutar el método **onCreate** y por ende la fotografía de perfil previamente cargada en el **ImageView** desaparece.

Así que mi pregunta es:

¿Existe alguna manera de poder almacenar en memoria la imagen de perfil que recibo a través del **InputStream**?

Lo que busco, es evitar el tener que consultar la API, cada vez que el usuario cambie la orientación del dispositivo móvil, y simplemente establecer de nueva cuenta la imagen de perfil previamente consultada.

De antemano, les agradezco cualquier ayuda posible.

A continuación, coloco los fragmentos de código correspondientes:

```
Activity LoginMicrosoftProfile.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_login"
    tools:context=".LoginMicrosoftProfile">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_card_view_img_profile"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin_elements_6">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_img_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_img_height"
                android:contentDescription="@string/text_alt_profile_img"
                android:src="@drawable/default_user_gray"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin_elements_2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements"
            android:text="@string/tv_hint_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_submit_txt_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements_6"
            tools:text="Juan Perez" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_job_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements"
            android:text="@string/tv_hint_job_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_job_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_submit_txt_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements_6"
            tools:text="Ingeniero" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements"
            android:text="@string/tv_hint_email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_submit_txt_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements_6"
            tools:text="alguien@gmail.com" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentVisitModules"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding_default"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin_elements_2"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/visitModules"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_btn_visit_modules"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/background_login_2"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding_default"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin_elements_2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_margin_elements_2"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signIn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/common_margin_elements"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@color/teal_700"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/btn_submit_text"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clearCache"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_btn_clear_cache"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/background_login_3"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:enabled="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

LoginMicrosoftProfile.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider; //Imports the Graph sdk Auth interface
import com.microsoft.graph.concurrency.ICallback;
import com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException;
import com.microsoft.graph.http.IHttpRequest;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.*;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationCallback; // Imports MSAL auth methods
import com.microsoft.identity.client.*;
import com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.*;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class LoginMicrosoftProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferencs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private final static String[] SCOPES = {"Files.Read", "User.Read"};
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /* Azure AD v2 Configs */
    final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    private ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication mSingleAccountApp;

    /* UI & Debugging Variables */

    Button signInButton;
    Button signOutButton;
    Button visitModules;

    //TextView logTextView;
    TextView currentUserTextView;
    TextView jobTitleTextView;
    TextView emailTextView;

    ImageView profile;
    LinearLayout visitModulesC;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_microsoft_profile);

        sharedPreferencs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = sharedPreferencs.edit();

        //Se inicializan los componentes de la interfaz

        initializeUI();

        //Se crea una aplicacion de cliente publica de cuenta unica (socket)

        PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(getApplicationContext(),
                R.raw.auth_config_single_account, new IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreated(ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
                        mSingleAccountApp = application;
                        loadAccount();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                        //displayError(exception); (Falta probar el toast)
                        displayErrorUser("¡Error al conectarse con el servidor!");
                    }
                });

    }

    private void loadAccount() {

        if (mSingleAccountApp == null) {
            return;
        }

        mSingleAccountApp.getCurrentAccountAsync(new ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.CurrentAccountCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onAccountLoaded(@Nullable IAccount activeAccount) {

                //Puedes usar los datos de la cuenta para actualizar la interfaz grafica o la base de datos de la aplicacion
                updateUI(activeAccount);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAccountChanged(@Nullable IAccount priorAccount, @Nullable IAccount currentAccount) {

                if (currentAccount == null) {
                    //Una tarea de limpieza para el cambio de sesion
                    performOperationOnSignOut();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull MsalException exception) {
                //displayError(exception); (Falta probar el toast)
                displayErrorUser("¡Error al cargar la cuenta!");
            }

        });

    }

    private void initializeUI(){

        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signIn);
        signOutButton = findViewById(R.id.clearCache);
        visitModules = findViewById(R.id.visitModules);

        //logTextView = findViewById(R.id.txt_log);
        currentUserTextView = findViewById(R.id.current_user);
        jobTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_job_title);
        emailTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_email);

        profile = findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
        visitModulesC = findViewById(R.id.contentVisitModules);

        //Se agrega un oyente al boton de iniciar sesión

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSingleAccountApp == null) {
                    return;
                }

                mSingleAccountApp.signIn(LoginMicrosoftProfile.this, null, SCOPES, getAuthInteractiveCallbackSignIn());

            }
        });

        //Se agrega un oyente al boton de cerrar sesion

        signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSingleAccountApp == null){
                    return;
                }

                mSingleAccountApp.signOut(new ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.SignOutCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSignOut() {

                        updateUI(null);
                        performOperationOnSignOut();

                        Intent back = new Intent(LoginMicrosoftProfile.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(back);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull MsalException exception){
                        //displayError(exception); (Falta probar el toast)
                        displayErrorUser("¡Error al cerrar la sesión!");
                    }

                });

            }
        });

        // Se agrega un oyente al boton de 'visitar modulos'

        visitModules.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (LoginMicrosoftProfile.this, LoadFilesUser.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private AuthenticationCallback getAuthInteractiveCallbackSignIn() {

        return new AuthenticationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {

                /* Se obtiene de manera exitosa un token, y se usara para la llamada a un recurso protegido - MSGraph */
                //Log.d(TAG, "¡Inicio de sesión exitoso!");

                /* Se llama a la API graph */
                callGraphAPISignIn(authenticationResult);

                /* Se realiza una pequeña pausa */
                suspendThread(15000, 1000);

                /* Actualizas la interfaz grafica (UI) */
                updateUI(authenticationResult.getAccount());

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(MsalException exception) {

                /* Error al adquirir el Token  (Si funciona) */
                //Log.d(TAG, "Error al iniciar sesión: " + exception.toString());

                displayErrorUser("¡Error al iniciar sesión!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

                /* El usuario cancela el ingreso de credenciales (login) (Si funciona) */
                //Log.d(TAG, "¡El usuario ha cancelado el Login!");

                displayErrorUser("¡Se ha cancelado el inicio de sesión!");
            }

        };

    }

    private void callGraphAPISignIn(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {

        final String accessToken = authenticationResult.getAccessToken();

        IGraphServiceClient graphClient =
                GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new IAuthenticationProvider() {
                            @Override
                            public void authenticateRequest(IHttpRequest request) {
                                //Log.d(TAG, "Solicitud de autenticación," + request.getRequestUrl());
                                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                            }
                        }).buildClient();

        graphClient.me().buildRequest().get(new ICallback<User>() {

            @Override
            public void success(final User user) {

                String dN = user.displayName != null ? user.displayName : "Desconocido";
                String jT = user.jobTitle != null ? user.jobTitle : "Ingeniero";
                String eM = user.mail != null ? user.mail : "docMX@contoso.edu.mx";

                //new UpdateUITask(currentUserTextView, jobTitleTextView, emailTextView).execute(dN, jT, eM);
                saveUserData(dN, jT, eM);

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                /* No funciona el toast */
                //displayError(ex);
            }

        });

        graphClient.me().photo().content().buildRequest().get(new ICallback<InputStream>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final InputStream inputStream) {

                if(inputStream != null) {
                    //PHOTO_USER = inputStream;
                    new DownloadImageTask(profile).execute(inputStream);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                //No funciona el toast
                //displayError(ex);
                profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user_green);
            }
        });

    }

    private SilentAuthenticationCallback getAuthSilentCallback() {

        return new SilentAuthenticationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "¡Inicio de sesión exitoso!");
                callGraphAPI(authenticationResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Error al iniciar sesión: " + exception.toString());
                displayError(exception);
            }

        };

    }

    private void callGraphAPI(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {

        final String accessToken = authenticationResult.getAccessToken();

        IGraphServiceClient graphClient =
                GraphServiceClient
                        .builder()
                        .authenticationProvider(new IAuthenticationProvider() {
                            @Override
                            public void authenticateRequest(IHttpRequest request) {
                                //Log.d(TAG, "Authenticating request," + request.getRequestUrl());
                                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                            }
                        })
                        .buildClient();

        graphClient
                .me()
                .drive()
                .buildRequest()
                .get(new ICallback<Drive>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(final Drive drive) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Found Drive " + drive.id);
                        //displayGraphResult(drive.getRawObject());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                        displayError(ex);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(@Nullable final IAccount account) {

        if (account != null) {

            //new DownloadImageTask(profile).execute();
            //currentUserTextView.setText("" + account.getClaims().get("name"));

            visitModulesC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            currentUserTextView.setText(sharedPreferencs.getString("dN", null));
            jobTitleTextView.setText(sharedPreferencs.getString("jT", null));
            emailTextView.setText(sharedPreferencs.getString("eM", null));

            signInButton.setEnabled(false);
            visitModules.setEnabled(true);
            signOutButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {

            visitModulesC.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            currentUserTextView.setText("");
            jobTitleTextView.setText("");
            emailTextView.setText("");

            signInButton.setEnabled(true);
            visitModules.setEnabled(false);
            signOutButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    private void displayError(@NonNull final Exception exception) {
        //logTextView.setText(exception.toString());
    }

    private void  displayErrorUser(@NonNull final String error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void performOperationOnSignOut() {
        final String signOutText = "¡Sesión finalizada!";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), signOutText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void displayGraphResult(@NonNull final String result) {
        emailTextView.setText(result);
    }

    private void saveUserData(@NonNull final String displayName, @NonNull final String jobTitle, @NonNull final String mail) {

        editor.putString("dN", displayName);
        editor.putString("jT", jobTitle);
        editor.putString("eM", mail);
        editor.apply();

    }

    private void suspendThread(int maxTime, int interval) {

        new CountDownTimer(maxTime, interval) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // do something after 1s
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // do something end times 5s
            }

        }.start();

    }

}
```

Este es el fragmento de código que me permite consultar y establecer la imagen en el **TextView**

```
graphClient.me().photo().content().buildRequest().get(new ICallback<InputStream>() {
    @Override
    public void success(final InputStream inputStream) {

        if(inputStream != null) {
            //PHOTO_USER = inputStream;
            new DownloadImageTask(profile).execute(inputStream);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(ClientException ex) {
        //displayError(ex);
        profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user_green);
    }
});
```

DownloadImageTask.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<InputStream, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(InputStream... inputStreams) {

        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;

        try {

            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStreams[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mIcon11;
    }

}
```

También comparto algunos links que tome de referencia:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-android

https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Lo que Android recomienda para evitar recargas innecesarias o llamadas innecesarias a APIs es implementar arquitectura limpia, para este caso concreto, el patrón conocido como MVVM. [Aquí tienes el punto de partida](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) si quieres implementar arquitectura limpia en Android.

Comment: Si lo que te interesa a guardar algo de forma permanente, entoces podrías optar por SharedPreferences, o por una base de datos integrada en la App, si se trata de una cantidad de datos considerables.